# How to search database using PHP with values containing multiple words?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, sqlite

I am working on a project in my PHP course where I have to create a database using SQLite for museums and countries they reside in, connect to that database from a webpage (using PHP/HTML) and generate a list of museums based on country chosen from a drop down list. The issue I am having is that I don't seem to be able to return data from country values with multiple words (United States, United Kingdom, etc.). It is working perfectly for single word countries. There is a pre-selection list generated that has the correct information, but the selection list is not generating correctly.

Here is a database sample (SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE museums (
    museum_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    museum_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    country TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO museums (museum_name, country) VALUES

('Louvre'  ,  'France'),
('State Hermitage Museum'  ,  'Russia'),
('National Museum of China'  ,  'China'),
('Metropolitan Museum of Art'  ,  'United States'),
('Vatican Museums'  ,  'Vatican City'),
('Tokyo National Museum'  ,  'Japan'),
('National Museum of Anthropology'  ,  'Mexico'),
('Victoria and Albert Museum'  ,  'United Kingdom'),
('National Museum of Korea'  ,  'South Korea'),
('Art Institute of Chicago'  ,  'United States');
```

Here is the PHP/HTML Code:

```
<?php

    $museumDb = new PDO('sqlite:museum.sqlite');
    $query = $museumDb->prepare('SELECT * FROM museums');
    $query->execute();
    $museums = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $country = $museumDb->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT country FROM museums ORDER BY country ASC');
    $country->execute();
    $countryLists = $country->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

 <form method="POST"> //selection form
   <fieldset>
      <legend><strong>Select from the drop down list below to narrow your search results by country</strong></legend>

      
        <select name="country" id="country">

           <?php foreach($countryLists as $countryList): ?>

           <!--Generates drop down list of countries from DB-issue may be here?-->
           <option value=<?php print $countryList['country']; ?>><?php print $countryList['country']; ?></option>     
           <?php endforeach; ?>
    
        </select>
       
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    

<?php if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        $countryName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['country']); //retrieves POST data from form selection
        print $countryName; //testing

        $new = $museumDb->prepare("SELECT country, museum_name FROM museums WHERE country = '$countryName'"); //sqlite query setting country = selected country from form
        $new->execute();
        $newLists = $new->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        print '<pre><code>';
        while ($row = $new->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {//testing
            var_dump($row);
        }
        

        var_dump($newLists); //testing query
        var_dump($new); //testing
        print '</code></pre>';
        ?>


<table><!--table not generating for countries with two words in name-->
     <tr>
          <th>Museum Name</th>
          <th>Country</th>
     </tr>
    
     <?php foreach ($newLists as $newList): ?>
            
          <tr>
              <td><?php print $newList['museum_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php print $newList['country']; ?></td>
          </tr>
            
      <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will convert the spaces to HTML entities which will not match what the DB values are. Instead, you should be using _parameterized queries_. They actually pretty easy to implement and should only be a 2 or 3 line change for you.

Comment: Use quotes for the value: `<option value="<?php print $countryList['country']; ?>">` like you did with every other attribute

Comment: I might be wrong re: `htmlspecialchars`. Looks like it doesn't transform spaces. But the advice re: parameterized queries still stands.

Comment: @brombeer Thank you! This is a problem I would've spent hours on just to find out its a tiny simple fix.

Comment: @waterloomatt thanks I will definitely look into parameterized queries to learn what they are all about. It appears brombeer's suggestion fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure how to mark this problem as answered, but a comment gave me the info I needed to change and it was a very simple fix.

Original line:

```
 <option value=<?php print $countryList['country']; ?>><?php print $countryList['country']; ?></option>
```

Fixed line:

```
 <option value="<?php print $countryList['country']; ?>"><?php print $countryList['country']; ?></option>
```

Thanks!